# dojox drawing rectangle connect method

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Dojox drawing api has rectangle as stencil which we can use on a drawing canvas. The docs mentions about a function called connect. how do i use it? `connect(o, e, s, m, once)`

Following is available in uncompressed dojo code.

```
// TODO: connect to a Shape event from outside class
connect: function(o, e, s, m, /* Boolean*/once){
// summary:
//      Convenience method for quick connects
//      See comments below for possiblities
//      functions can be strings
// once:
//      If true, the connection happens only
//      once then disconnects. Five args are required
//      for this functionality.
```

It is not clear why and how to use this function. Could some help me with the usage and functionality of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four methods are passed to `dojo.connect`.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/connect.html#usage

- o - object
- e - event
- s - scope or context
- m - method

Connect the event of this object to the method with the scope.

```
dojo.connect(domNode, 'click', { test: 1}, function() {
  var t = this test;
  // is one because 'this' is the scope we pass the connect method. 
});
```

The function will be executed every time the particular dom node is clicked on.

The last argument `once` is specific to the convenience method.  If true, the function will be executed only once.  After being executed, the handler will be disconnected.

Comment: Since i am using rectangle in the drawing api. my domNode is complete drawing canvas. i could not get the domNode of rectangle alone. So i know the data points of the rectangle and i based on the event.localX and localY co-ordinates. i find if the click has happened inside the rectangle.

Comment: This is not working in internet Explorer. any idea on reasons?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?